# Can I use java 'keytool' to generate Outlook certificate for Windows10

Tags: java, security, windows-10, certificate

I am having problem with the certificate generated by Java ‘keytool’ (jdk 8) utility which I am trying to use with Microsoft Outlook 2016 in Windows 10.

1. I have generated self-signed certificate using java “keytool” utility.
2. Using ‘keytool’ I have exported it to PKCS#12 key store
3. Using ‘openssl’ I have extracted (from just created key store) my private key and certificate.
4. Using ‘openssl’ I have then created jd.pfx certificate from my private key ‘jd.key’ and certificate ‘jd.pem’.
5. I then imported ‘jd.pfx’ to my windows 10 database using certmgr.msc windows tool.
6. When I open the certificate using Microsoft ‘certmgr.msc’ tool it shows me the message: “A system-level error occurred while verifying trust”.

Screen shot here:
[Certificate Properties from Double Click in certmgr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKi9A.png)

Has anybody came across this problem?
This certificate works perfectly on Windows 7.

Thanks,
Janusz

Comment: Try "Install Certificate..."; obviously you can't verify trust - it's a self-signed key. I assume you trust yourself.

Comment: Sorry. I did not mention in my post that I have put that certificate into “Trusted Root Certification Authorities” (its for a development purpose) – so it is trusted. I have tested that on Windows 7 and that works – so I don’t understand why Windows Certificate Manager in Windows 10 has a problem with that certificate.